# Explanation of this step in a modular arithmetic problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse

> The multiplicative inverse of $5$ is $7$, when using mod $34$.
>   $$\begin{align*}
> 5\cdot x&=3\\[0.1in]
> 7\cdot 5\cdot x &=7\cdot 3\\[0.1in]
> 1\cdot x &=7\cdot 3\\[0.1in]
> x&=21
> \end{align*}$$

I don't understand this part:

$$\begin{align*}
7\cdot 5\cdot x &=7\cdot 3\\[0.1in]
1\cdot x &=7\cdot 3
\end{align*}$$

How is 7*5*x the same as 1*x?

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $a\equiv b\bmod n$ precisely when $n$ divides the difference $a-b$. Therefore, we have
$$35\equiv 1\bmod 34.$$
It is also true that if $a\equiv b \bmod n$, then $ac\equiv bc\bmod n$ for any $c$. Therefore, whatever $x$ is,
$$35x\equiv x\bmod 34,$$
so that we can go from
$$35x\equiv 21\bmod 34$$
to
$$x\equiv 21\bmod 34.$$

Comment: Why is it possible to replace xmod34 with 21mod34? And how did 35x disappeare?

Comment: That's not what I did - we know that
$$35x\equiv 21\bmod 34,$$
and replacing $35x$ by $x$ (as I explained), we *obtain*
$$x\equiv 21\bmod 34.$$
Of course, this *conclusion* means that we can replace $x$ by $21$ or vice versa when working modulo $34$; think of $\Box\equiv\Box\bmod 34$ as its own sort of "equals sign".

Comment: If $r\equiv s\bmod n$ and $r\equiv t\bmod n$, then $s\equiv t\bmod n$ (just like is true with usual equals signs). Therefore, if
$$35x\equiv x\bmod 34$$
and 
$$35x\equiv 21\bmod 34$$
then
$$x\equiv 21\bmod 34.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $5x = 3 \pmod{34}$, you can multiply both sides of this equation by $7$ (the inverse of $5$ to obtain $7 \cdot 5x = 7 \cdot 3 \pmod{34}$. (The reason why this works is because $a=b \pmod{n}$ implies $ca = cb \pmod{n}$, and you should check this yourself if you haven't.)

Therefore since 
$$
7 \cdot 5 = 35 = 34 + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1 \pmod{34},
$$ 
we obtain 
$$
x = 1 \cdot x = 7 \cdot 5 \cdot x  = 7 \cdot 3 = 21 \pmod{34}.
$$

Hope that helps,

Comment: Perhaps I should've flipped things around. Is that better?

Comment: @user8005 : Saying that $35 = 1 \pmod{34}$ means that $34$ divides $35-1 = 34$. If $34$ is a multiple of $34$, then so is $34x = (35-1)x = 35 x - 1x$. That is what the equation $35x = 1x \pmod{34}$ says.